# Update Dynamics Nav 2013 using asp.net web application

Tags: c#, .net, navision, dynamics-nav-2013

a customer has asked me to create a web app to let him insert records in a custom Navision 2013 table.
Is it possible to di this using the nav soap web service, considering that the table in question is a custom one? if so, how can i expose in the web service our custom table/page/records?
I know i can do that using raw sql queries, as i've done that in the past, but using a web service would be better, because the user would be authenticated using his domain credential in the nav web serivice, and thus his inserted records would be only realtive to his identity in nav (nav is using windows auth).
All the code would be writter in .net c#.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an object in the object designer called "Web Services" [Page object 810]....in order to expose any page or codeunit as a soap-based web service you need to add it to this table and select Published if it is a page or if the codeunit is to be exposed as its own web service.  If you want to extend page web services then you need to add the codeunit with the same name as the page object and then you would not select published.

Once you've exposed the web service in this manner you would go to your web application and add a Service Reference or Web Reference with the following url structure:

http://[yourDynamicsNavServer]:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/[UrlEncodedCompanyName]/[WebServiceName]

or to get a listing of all available web service objects you could use the following url:

http://[yourDynamicsNavServer]:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Services